# Hands on Programming with R, Chapter 7, p.176, Can you make 'score' function treat 'DD' as wild card?

Tags: r

In chapter 7, the author score function:

```
score <- function(symbols) {
  same <- symbols[1] == symbols[2] && symbols[2] == symbols[3]
  bars <- symbols %in% c('B', 'BB', 'BBB')
  
  if (same) {
    payouts <- c('DD' = 100, '7' = 80, 'BBB' = 40, 'BB' = 25, 'B' = 10, 'C' = 10, '0' = 0)
    prize <- unname(payouts[symbols[1]])
  } else if (all(bars)) {
    prize <- 5
  } else {
    cherries <- sum('C' == symbols)
    prize <- 2*cherries+1*(cherries == 2)
  }
  
  diamonds <- sum('DD' == symbols)
  prize*(2^diamonds)
}
```

Where 'symbols' is a vector with 3 components of slot machine. This looks neat and clean but this does not treat 'DD' as wild card. So I made my own version of score(), which do treat 'DD'as wild card.

```
score <- function(symbols) {
  bars <- symbols %in% c('BBB', 'BB', 'B')
  if (all(symbols == symbols[1]) | (length(unique(symbols)) == 2 & any(symbols == 'DD'))) {
    
    a_diamond <- c('7' = 80, 'BBB' = 40, 'BB' = 25, 'B' = 10, 'C' = 10, '0' = 0)
    diamonds <- c('DD' = 100, '7' = 80, 'BBB' = 40, 'BB' = 25, 'B' = 10, 'C' = 10, '0' = 0)
    IsDD <- list(diamonds, a_diamond)
    payout_index <- sum(length(unique(symbols)))
    payouts <- IsDD[[payout_index]]
    prize_index <- unique(symbols[symbols %in% names(payouts)]) == names(payouts)
    prize <- unname(payouts[prize_index])
  } else if (all(bars)) {
    prize <- 5
  } else {
    prize <- c(0,2,5)[sum(symbols == 'C')+1]
  }
  
  prize*(2^sum(symbols == 'DD'))
}
```

But it looks messy. Can you make it cleaner?

I'm using 64 bit R version 3.6.3

Comment: What do you mean by a wild card, a function's input variable?

Comment: It's a symbol that can be treated like other symbols in some special case. For example, where symbols is c('DD', '7', '7'), 'DD' is treated like '7', so it scores 80, and because of one 'DD' in the symbols, the score doubles. But 'DD' does not become 'C', where symbols has no point in the first place. For example, c('0', 'DD', '0') is not treated as c('0', 'C', '0'). Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively simple way is to keep the function largely as is, albeit rearranged somewhat.  Move the calculation of the number of diamonds in the spin and the payout vector to the top and use the result of diamonds as a condition of replacing any diamonds with the symbol of the next highest value in the spin.

```
score <- function(symbols) {
  diamonds <- sum('DD' == symbols)
  payouts <- c('DD' = 100, '7' = 80, 'BBB' = 40, 'BB' = 25, 'B' = 10, 'C' = 10, '0' = 0)
  if (diamonds == 1 || diamonds == 2) symbols <- replace(symbols, symbols == "DD", names(payouts)[min(match(symbols, names(payouts)[-1]), na.rm = TRUE) + 1] )
  same <- symbols[1] == symbols[2] && symbols[2] == symbols[3]
  bars <- symbols %in% c('B', 'BB', 'BBB')
  if (same) {
    prize <- unname(payouts[symbols[1]])
  } else if (all(bars)) {
    prize <- 5
  } else {
    cherries <- sum('C' == symbols)
    prize <- 2*cherries+1*(cherries == 2)
  }
  prize*(2^diamonds)
}
```

Some tests based on Table 9.1 [here](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/programs.html):

```
# Expected results: 10, 320, 40, 0
sapply(list(c("C", "0", "DD"),
        c("7", "DD", "DD"),
        c("DD", "B", "DD"),
        c("DD", "0", "7")), score)

[1]  10 320  40   0
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Much cleaner!